# Filter out an element's classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the most efficient way to filter the list of classes on a given element?

```
<div class="foo bar"></div>
<div class="bim bar"></div>

$("div.bar").click(function(ev) {
  alert("The non-bar class was:" + ???);
});
```

I know I could write a for-loop to go through the ev.currentTarget.classList but I want to know if there's a better way.

EDIT: I'd like to clarify that I want the alert to tell me "foo" and "bim." I don't want to *replace* "bar," I just want to be able to access the classes that are NOT bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no *jQuery* way to get this, but I would do:

```
$("div.bar").click(function(ev) {
    var nonBarClasses = (' ' + this.className + ' ').replace(' bar ', ' ').split(/ +/);

    nonBarClasses.shift();
    nonBarClasses.pop();

    // nonBarClasses is now an array, with each element a class that isn't `bar`

    alert("The non-bar class was: " + nonBarClasses.join(" ")); 
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/PpUeX/2

Comment: I think you're making it a little too complicated. What about http://jsfiddle.net/ZkucZ/1/?

Comment: @pimvdb: I wouldn't say using a `filter` function over String.replace  is less complicated; especially when the question is asking for efficiency. Plus `Array.filter` isn't supported in IE < 8.

Comment: Touche, I missed efficiency. Though, yours currently includes an extraneous element. http://jsfiddle.net/PpUeX/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can get the entire class string from the element by using [`jQuery.fn.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and then [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) it into an array, with which you can do anything you want.

```
$("div.bar").click(function(ev) {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); // [0:'foo', 1:'bar']
});
```

EDIT: As for providing a "jQuery"-way of getting all of the non-"bar" classes, you could make a temporary [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of the clicked element and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) the bar class before you do anything with it:

```
$("div.bar").click(function(ev) {
  var noBarClasses = $(this)
    .clone().removeClass('bar') // <-- no more "bar"
    .attr('class').split(' '); // [0:'foo']
});
```